# VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT flag magically added to swapchain images

Tags: graphics, gpu, render, vulkan

Is the `VkImageUsageFlagBits::VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT` supposed to automatically be set for swapchain images?

I've been looking it up, and I don'd see any indication that this flag is supposed to be automatically added to swapchain images.

However, I have tested that in SDK 1.2.148.1 (haven't tried others), on NVIDIA GTX 1080ti with the latest drivers, that flag is automatically added, even when not requested. I'm not sure whether it's the SDK or the driver that it's setting it, but one of them is.

I first verified it in my own code, then tried it using the Sascha Willem's Triangle example, by commenting out the following line:
https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/VulkanSwapChain.cpp#L347

This is an image with the Triangle app running on NVIDIA Nsight. It shouldn't have the flag:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epogX.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "supposed to be"? If the flag is available, you *can* use it. You linked to code showing someone using it if it is available. I'm not sure what's wrong with that.

Comment: "*that flag is automatically added, even when not requested.*" How do you know that? You cannot ask a `VkImage` what its usage flags are.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I initially found out by debugging an issue that I encountered while converting some exiting code to use Imageless Framebuffers. The validation layers where complaining about the swapchain image and the framebuffer config not having matching flags. The error message showed the value of the swapchain image flags. Additionally, I also confirmed it with NVIDIA Insight, as the image in the post shows.

Comment: "What do you mean by 'supposed to be'?": I'm asking whether this automatic flag setting is a feature or a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Vulkan has no mechanism to tell you what the usage flags are on an image, whether swapchain or not. As such, you are relying on layers and debugging tools to feed that information to you.

However, these tools *themselves* are perfectly capable of setting these flags. If a debugging tool wants to be able to show you the image data in a swapchain image, then that image must be usable as the source for a transfer operation. So such a tool must set those flags. The same goes for any layers that might be involved in debugging.

Indeed, the fact that the debugging tool knows that the flag has been set is evidence that the Vulkan *implementation* didn't set it. If it had set the flag, nobody outside of the implementation would know about it.

So in all likelihood, this is the act of a debugging layer. Unfortunately, it is setting this flag before the validation layer sees it. And to validate uses of the imageless framebuffer feature, the validation layer needs to look at those flags.

To fix this, you may be able to reorder the layers you have activated. `ppEnabledLayerNames` is an ordered list of layers; if you aren't doing so already, put the validation layers first in this list. If you're enabling layers more globally, see if you can play around with the order of those layers.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree that a debugging tool needs to clobber the data to get the data. NVIDIA has access to their own GPU internals -- they need not change user bits to poke around their own data structures. Perhaps the validation layers, have a bug, I don't know, but they also don't need to change bits to see the flags. They can intercept that before it gets send off somewhere. The API dump feature of the Vulkan Configurator shows the TRANSFER_SRC flag set, so it's not NV Insight that's doing it, at least.

Comment: I have no choice but to work around. However, it requires to put in a hack to enable the transfer flag in the imageless framebuffer definition associated with the swapchain images; otherwise, there are validation errors. If when the bug gets fixed, then the hack will need to be removed to prevent another validation error.

Comment: If it's an imageless framebuffer... why are you using a swapchain image with it at all?

Comment: I'm confused. What does the image being part of the swapchain matter for it being part of the framebuffer?

Comment: Oh, when you said "imageless framebuffer", I thought you meant "I'm rendering without any attached images". I'd forgotten that there is a Vulkan 1.2 feature literally called "imageless framebuffer".

Comment: @Vulkanoid: I've added a suggestion for something you could try to alleviate it.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround suggestion. I re-compiled with validation layers disabled and the flag is still present (verified via Nsignt). I drilled into the VulkanHPP  swapchain creation, via the mvsc debugger, as far down as it would let me, but saw no shenanigans. Maybe it's a driver bug. For now, I'll just live with my workaround, to add the Transfer flag to the framebuffer image metadata definition. I'll revisit this again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can set imageUsage bit in [VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR.html)